# Calculating Homography for Image Stitching

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, projective-transformations

Given two images that were taken from the same camera by pure rotation about the camera center, I am trying to stitch the images.

I identified the 4 corresponding pair of points by loading in the images using MATLAB's built-in getpts function and identifying similar points of interest across both images. I used the corners of the rooftop buildings as the matching pairs.

This process results in the following points:

```
city_one_points = [478 137; 616 113; 660 187; 518 271];
city_two_points_one = [878 131; 1024 121; 1062 197; 918 273];
```

Once the points are identified, I pass them into my compute homography function.

```
H12 = compute_homography(city_one_points, city_two_points_one);
```

Once the homography is computed, I attempt to stitch the images but I do not get a side by side stitched image.

```
tform_h12 = projective2d(H12);
city_one_projected = imwarp(city_one, tform_h12, 'OutputView', imref2d(size(city_two)));

figure;
imshow(city_one_projected);
```

I am pretty sure my homography function is correct.

I do have doubts on whether I am sourcing the corresponding pair points correctly. Do I have to do any additional processing on the points once they have been identified across both images?

Is my stitching process incorrect?

Attached as references are the compute_homography function and the two reference images that I am using.

```
function H = compute_homography(pts1,pts2)
    % pts1 -> 3 x 4
    % pts2 -> H x pts1
    % H -> 3 x 3
    % pt2 holds the points of the reference image
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Direct Linear Transformation (DLT) Algorithm                       %
    % Given n >= 4 2D to 2D point correspondences {xi <-> xi'},          %
    % determine the 2D Homography matrix H such that xi' = Hxi           %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % i. For each correspondence xi <-> xi' compute the matrix Ai from   %
    %    (4.1). Ai*h = 0 (zero vector)   
    %    h = [h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8 h9]^T
    % ii. Assemble the n 2 x 9 matrices Ai into a single 2n x 9 matrix A  %
    % iii. Obtain the SVD of A. The unit singular vector corresponding   %
    %      to the smallest singular value is the solution h.
    % iv. The matrix H is determined from h as in (4.2).
    pts1 = pts1';
    pts2 = pts2';

    [~,column] = size(pts1);

    % Iterate over each point and its corresponding point and find Ai
    % Row -> xi,yi,wi
    % size of A will be 2n x 9
    A = zeros(2*column,9);

    % (Assemble the n 2 × 9 matrices Ai into a single 2n × 9 matrix A.
    for i=1:column
        x = pts1(1,i);
        y =  pts1(2,i);
        x_prime = pts2(1,i);
        y_prime = pts2(2,i);

        A(2*i-1,:) = [-x, -y, -1, 0, 0, 0, x*x_prime, y*x_prime, x_prime];
        A(2*i,:) = [0, 0, 0, -x, -y, -1, x*y_prime, y*y_prime, y_prime];
    end
    
    % Obtain the SVD and get the smallest singular value of V.
    [~,~,V] = svd(A);
    h = V(:,9);
    H = reshape(h,[3,3]);
end
```

[image: city1.jpg]
[image: city2.jpg]